# Is there a name for the weighted sum where the sum of squares of the weights is 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, terminology

A combination $\sum_i \alpha_i x_i$ with $\alpha_i \geq 0$ and $\sum_i \alpha_i = 1$ is called a convex combination, which is a type of linear combination.

Is there a name for $\sum_i \alpha_i x_i$ when the constraint is instead $\alpha_i \geq 0$ and  $\sum_i \alpha_i^2 = 1$?

Comment: Not a name, but a geometric interpretation: the constraint means $\alpha$ is a normalized vector, and $\sum \alpha_i x_i$ is a dot product, which measures how much the vector $x$ is aligned with $\alpha$.

Comment: Call it a "spherical combination"